# Google Sheet Script in need of assistance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm having issues with my google sheets script because it always has this error :    Error
Exceeded maximum execution time. How can i solve this issue

```
function transposeData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Determine the total number of rows
  var totalRows = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Loop through each row
  for (var r = 2; r <= totalRows; r++) {

    // Get data for the row
    var data = sheet.getRange(r, 14, 1, 76 - 14 + 1).getValues()[0]; // Get values of cells N2 through BX2
  
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 6) {
      // Get next group of 6 columns, or fewer if not enough remain
      var group = data.slice(i, Math.min(i + 6, data.length));
      output.push(group);
    }

    // Get corresponding value from column A
    var correspondingValue = sheet.getRange(r, 1).getValue();

    // Find the last filled row
    var lastFilledRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    // Write each group into its own row, starting from the last filled row
    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
      var row = output[i];
      
      // Check if the group is non-empty
      var nonEmptyCells = row.filter(function(cell) {
        return cell !== "";
      });

      if (nonEmptyCells.length > 0) {
        // Write transposed data
        sheet.getRange(lastFilledRow + 1 + i, 14, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

        // Write corresponding value from column A
        sheet.getRange(lastFilledRow + 1 + i, 1).setValue(correspondingValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to reduce the time taken but I am a beginner at coding.

Comment: You are looping through the rows, but you are getting the values for the row _INSIDE_ the loop. That (mainly) is what is slowing you down. You need to do something like `var data = sheet.getDataRange.getValues()` **BEFORE** the loop. Then, inside the loop, you can reference each row of `data`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. is it possible for you to show me a full script example, because to be honest i have no idea how to code. Really appreciate it :))))

Answer (score 0):

You have a script that is exceeding the max allowance time for execution.

There are two obvious causes and solutions:

**#1: `GETVALUES`**
**Issue**

- obtained *WITHIN* the "row-by-row loop"

**Solution**

- get the data (including Column A) *BEFORE* the "row-by-row loop"
- use `getDataRange` or declare a range manually

**#2: `SETVALUE/SETVALUES`**
**Issue**

- used on a row-by-row basis *WITHIN* the loop.

**Solution**

- create arrays for the relevant Column A and Row data that can be used to `setvalues` in a single line of code each in the last lines of the script

It is entirely likely that there are more sophisticated ways determine loop values but that is for others to suggest.

---

```
function transposeData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3")

  // Determine the total number of rows
  var totalRows = sheet.getLastRow();

  // set some variables
  var numofHeaderRows = 1
  var columnA = 1
  var columnN = 14
  var columnBX = 76

  // set temporary Array for Column A values 
  var colAColArray = new Array
  // set temporary array for row data values
  var rowDataArray = new Array

  // get the range and data
  var range = sheet.getRange(numofHeaderRows+1,columnA,totalRows-numofHeaderRows,columnBX)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: start row:"+(numofHeaderRows+1)+", start column:"+columnA+", number of rows: "+(totalRows-numofHeaderRows)+", number of columns:"+columnBX) 
  var data = range.getValues()

  // get the number of columns of data
  var colsofData = columnBX-columnN+1
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: data range: "+range.getA1Notation()+", data length = "+data.length+", columns of Data = "+colsofData)

  // Loop through each row of data
  for (var r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {

    var output = [];
    // Get next group of 6 columns, or fewer if not enough remain, for this row
    
    for (var i = 0; i < colsofData; i += 6) {
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: r: "+r+", i: "+i+", slice: start = "+(i+columnN-1)+", Min value1: "+(i+columnN+6-1)+", Min Value 2: "+columnBX)    
      var group = data[r].slice((i+columnN-1), Math.min((i+columnN+6-1), columnBX))
      // Logger.log(group) // DEBUG

      // test for 6 values, if not then add null values
      if (group.length !== 6){
        var adjGroup = []
        adjGroup = Array(6-group.length).fill(null)
        group = group.concat(adjGroup);
        // Logger.log(group) // DEBUG
      }
      output.push(group);
    }  
    // Logger.log(output) // DEBUG
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: output length: "+output.length)

    // Get corresponding value from column A
    var correspondingValue = data[r][0]
    
    // Write each group into its own row, starting from the last filled row
    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {

      //Logger.log("DEBUG: r: "+r+", i:"+i+", corresponding value: "+correspondingValue+" colA array: "+colAColArray)
      var row = []
      row = output[i];
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: r: "+r+", i:"+i+", row "+row)
      // Logger.log(row) // DEBUG

      // Write transposed data
      rowDataArray.push(row)
      // Write corresponding value from column A
      colAColArray.push([correspondingValue])
     
    }// end of writing row data
  } // end of row-by-row loop

  // Logger.log(colAColArray)  // DEBUG
  // Logger.log(colAColArray.length) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log(rowDataArray) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log(rowDataArray.length) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log(totalRows)

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: ColA data range = "+sheet.getRange(totalRows+1,1,colAColArray.length).getA1Notation())
  sheet.getRange(totalRows+1,1,colAColArray.length).setValues(colAColArray)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: row data range = "+sheet.getRange(totalRows+1,columnN,rowDataArray.length,6).getA1Notation())
  sheet.getRange(totalRows+1,columnN,rowDataArray.length,6).setValues(rowDataArray)
}
```